# Webdriver not returning some data

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to get some information from a website. The Web Inspector shows the html source, with what JavaScript rendered into it. So I wanted to use chromedriver to render it for the purpose of extracting certain information, which cannot be accessed by simply requesting the website.

Now what seems confusing, is that even the driver is not returning anything.
My code looks like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/Chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all("tr", class_="odd")
```

And the website is:
https://www.amundietf.co.uk/professional/product/view/LU1681038243

Is there anything else that gets rendered into the html, when the Web Inspector is opened, which Chromedriver is not able to handle?
Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. I've executed the exact same code and was able to extract the tr rows.

Comment: I only get empty brackets when I try to print the result like this: `[]`

Comment: may be network latency, pls put a sleep or wait after driver.get(url). also do you see page with details on browser?

Comment: Can you (1) create a screenshot and check and show if the site is rendered
`driver.save_screenshot('test.jpg')`,
(2) check if the soup has some contents through `soup.text` and (3) check if you can visit this site at all from your IP?

Comment: @simpleApp letting the program sleep for 3 seconds returns something, though is there a way to have an `await` or something similar in python

Comment: they are more like sync wait, some other testing framework support await for angular or react tech stack but they are mainly on Jave script. for python pls refer https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Do you accept cookies in your code?

Answer (score 0):

At least you need to accept privacy settings, than click `validateDisclaimer` to site:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.amundietf.co.uk/professional/product/view/LU1681038243"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("footer_tc_privacy_button_3").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("validateDisclaimer").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fpFrame.fpBannerMore #blockleft>#part_principale_1")))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all("tr", class_="odd")
print(results)
```

After it you need to wait for your page to load and to define elements you are looking for correctly.
Your question really contains many questions, that should be solved one by one.
I just pointed out the first of the problems.

**Update**
I solved the issue.
You will need to parse result by yourself.
So, you had problems:

1. Did not click two buttons.
2. Did not wait for a table you need to load.
3. Did not have any waits. In Selenium you must use them.